# Getting -1 while data transfer using bulktransfer()

Tags: android, android-camera

I am working on an application which needs data communication between Android phone and Camera. Android phone and camera connected via usb.

I can read and write data first time with `bulkTransfer()`,but  when I try it for second time, I am getting negative 1. 
I also tried with different timeout. Any kind of suggestion is highly appreciated.

My code is given bellow

```
public int process()
{
    // prepare the command data
    ContainerCommand data = prepareCommand();

    int reqSize = data.size();
    data.prepareRequest(outBuffer);

    if (! skipLogging) {
        Log.i(TAG, "-== Ready to send Command [**- " + commandName + " -**] ==-");
        if (OperationCode.debugVerbose) {
            Log.v(TAG, data.toString());
            Log.v(TAG, StringUtility.dumpByteArray(outBuffer, reqSize));
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "reqLen: " + reqSize);
    }

    int sentLen;
    sentLen = usbConnection.bulkTransfer(epHost2Camera, outBuffer, reqSize, usbTimeout);
    if (sentLen != reqSize) {
        if (! skipLogging) {
            Log.w(TAG, "******--- UNEXPECTED send len:" + sentLen);
        }
        return UsbCameraConstants.RET_GENERAL_ERROR;
    }

    int resultCode;
    resultCode = sendExtraData4Command();
    if (resultCode != UsbCameraConstants.RET_SUCCESSFULLY_DONE) {
        if (! skipLogging) {
            Log.w(TAG, "******--- UNEXPECTED extra data send for command! retCode:" 
                    +  short2Hex(resultCode) );
        }
        return resultCode;          
    }

    resultCode = UsbCameraConstants.RET_GENERAL_ERROR;
    // get response
    int readLen;
    boolean responseGet = false;
    boolean errorFound = false;

    readLen = usbConnection.bulkTransfer(epCamera2Host, inBuffer
            , maxInPacketSize, usbTimeout);
    if (! skipLogging) {
        Log.d(TAG, "******--- Got first response, read len:" + readLen);
    }
    if (readLen <= 0) {
        if (! skipLogging) {
            Log.w(TAG, "******--- UNEXPECTED read len:" + readLen);
        }
        errorFound = true;  
    }
    while ((readLen > 0) && (! responseGet) && (! errorFound)) {
        ContainerBase container = null;
        try {
            container = ContainerBase.parseBaseValue(inBuffer, 0, readLen);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse container packet!", e);
            errorFound = true;
            resultCode = UsbCameraConstants.RET_GENERAL_ERROR;
        }
        if (container != null) {
            if (! skipLogging) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Response packet basic information:" + container.toString());
                if (OperationCode.debugVerbose) { 
                    Log.v(TAG, StringUtility.dumpByteArray(inBuffer, readLen));
                }
            }
            if (container.type == ContainerBase.TYPE_DATA_BLOCK) {
                // need read again
                if (! skipLogging) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Data container block found!");
                }
                if (readLen > leastPacketSize) {
                    // need process the data content
                    if (! processDataBlock(container.length, readLen) ) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to Process Data Packet!");
                        errorFound = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (container.type == ContainerBase.TYPE_RESPONSE_BLOCK) {
                resultCode = container.code;
                if (! skipLogging) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Response container block found! retCode:" + short2Hex(resultCode));
                }
                responseGet = true;
                if (! processResponseBlock() ) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Failed to Process Response Packet!");
                }
            }
            if (! responseGet) {
                do {
                    readLen = usbConnection.bulkTransfer(epCamera2Host, inBuffer
                            , maxInPacketSize, usbTimeout);
                    if (! skipLogging) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "******--- Got packet from endpoint Camera2Host, read len:" 
                                    + readLen);
                    }
                    if (readLen == 0) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "***ReadLen=0, camera data not ready yet. sleep a little while!");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50L); // 50 milliseconds
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            // do nothing
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }                       
                } while (readLen == 0);

            }
        }


    }

    return resultCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to solve you problem with the information provided.

I am writing this as an answer and not a comment, because I want room to present you some possibilities that may be the cause of you problem.

`-1` return from `bulkTransfer` means there was some error reading or writing.

It could be a timeout issue, but also connection issue or protocol issue.

You need to check the following possibilities:

1. Is your USB cable in good condition, and the connectors are properly plugged in?
   It is possible that the physical connection is unstable and you are loosing the camera.
2. What is the camera protocol?
   It is possible that you need to do something between sending commands, like reset the interface, send some command on endpoint 0 via control transfer, etc.
3. Was the command you sent correct?
4. Did you remember to claim the interface?
5. Is the code that opens the USB connection in the same thread as the code that sends commands?
   It is possible that some other part of your application is closing the connection while you are trying to send commands.
6. Did you set the correct configuration for the camera USB?
   Some USB devices have more than one configuration.

At the very least, I suggest you add the exact model of the camera you are using to your question, so that if someone is familiar with its protocol can advise you.

Also, unless you have a protocol document for the camera, I would recommend you connect it to a PC, and use WireSHark USB module or another USB capture software to monitor the protocol and learn how to implement it.